# Is there a quota limit for SoundCloud API?

Tags: android, soundcloud

I have an android app using SoundCloud API. Some of my users complaining about connection issues. Is there a quota limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#quotas

But it doesn't tell us the exact number:

> We reserve the right, at our discretion, to impose restrictions and
>   limitations on the number and frequency of calls made by your app to
>   the SoundCloud® API. You must not attempt to circumvent any
>   restrictions or limitations that we impose.

As commented by Arsalan, here is more information:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits#errors

> #### Rate Limits
>
> All rate limits on the SoundCloud API are currently calculated against a client application's client id.
>
> #### Global Rate Limit
>
> We currently do not enforce any limit on the total number of calls made by a client application in aggregate.
>
> #### Rate Limit on Play Requests
>
> Effective July 1, all requests that result in access to a playable stream are subject to a limit of 15,000 requests per any 24-hour time window. Currently, this is inclusive of all requests that are made to /tracks/:id/stream.
>
> After a previous time window has expired, a new time window starts from the first request made.
>
> The majority of SoundCloud API rate limits are in the form of 24-hour time windows.

Comment: Rate limits are describe at this link : https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits

Answer (score 0):

According Terms of Use, API calls are limited to 15,000 per app per day.

> We reserve the right, at our discretion, to impose restrictions and limitations on the number and frequency of calls made by your app to the SoundCloud® API. You must not attempt to circumvent any restrictions or limitations that we impose. Presently, API calls are limited to 15,000 per app per day.

See https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#quotas

Comment: So, say, if your service (app) does have:
- 1000 daily active users, they get only 15 streamed tracks per day
- 5000 daily active users, they get only 3 streamed tracks per day
- 10000 daily active users, they get only 1.5 streamed tracks per day

It doesn't surprise me that there aren't a lot of integration with SoundCould. 
Dear SoundCloud, if you want developers to boost your service by building robust integrations with your platform please don't be so stingy. There are many other ways to protect your API from abuse!